# Weird .htaccess password request that I didn't make

Tags: html, .htaccess, authentication, passwords

Okay. So I went on a trip, came back, and suddenly, a website that I was working on is now asking for a username and password á la .htaccess. Thing is, I never made this happen and there is no .htaccess file anywhere to be found. Here is the site: link

I didn't buy the template from omegathemes.com, whatever that is. And when you go there, it asks for the same kind of user and password.

Any help?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, more a question about what software you may have installed (which you provide no information about other than a missing link) or who may have changed something while you were on vacation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a reference in the `js/jquery.ad-gallery.js` file. It seems to load a loader image from omegathemes.com as default. Because that URL is protected by a password, it pops up when your script loads.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.adGallery = function(options) {
    var defaults = { loader_image: 'http://omegathemes.com/tf/interior-designs/images/loader.gif',
                     start_at_index: 0,
                     thumb_opacity: 0.8,
                     animate_first_image: false,
                     animation_speed: 400,
```

Just remove the reference and replace it by a valid URL to a loader image on your domain.